# Datepicker functionality

Tags: html, angularjs, bootstrap-4

Have a single page web app and below is my HTML tag. I have used datepicker function in my HTML and need help to disable the date field when the web page is loading (to fetch data from DB in the back ground). In other words, currently, when the user selects a specific month ex: Nov 2018, the page runs for for few seconds as it has to fetch the needed data from the DB in the back end, I could still see that the other months are still available to select. hence, I need the date field to be disabled/unavailable to select when the page is loading to fetch the data in the back end for a specific month.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<title>XXXXX </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="././javascript/dpe.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/i18n/defaults-zh_TW.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="././javascript/week.js"></script> -->
</head>


<style>
.inner-addon {
    position: relative;
}

/* style icon */
.inner-addon .glyphicon {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

/* align icon */
.left-addon .glyphicon {
    left: 0px;
}

.right-addon .glyphicon {
    right: 0px;
}

/* add padding  */
.left-addon input {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.right-addon input {
    padding-right: 30px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var testId = "${testId}";
    function dateChange(newdate) {
        var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('dpeDashboard'))
                .scope();
        scope.dateChange(newdate);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#testDate, #dpCal').datepicker({
            minViewMode : 1,
            autoclose : true,
            format : 'MM, yyyy'

        }).datepicker('setDate', 'today');


        var date = "";

    });

    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(
            function() {

                $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html(
                        $(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
                $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val(
                        $(this).data('value'));
            });
</script>

<div class="page-header">
            <h1>Welcome to XXXXX</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-5"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <form ng-submit="submitData()">

                                <div id="wait"
                                    style="display: none; width: 69px; height: 89px; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 30%; padding: 2px;">
                                    <img src='demo_wait.gif' width="200" height="200" /> <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;Loading..
                                </div>
                                <div class='input-group date' id="testDate">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="selDate"
                                        onchange="dateChange(this.value);"
                                        placeholder="click to Select Month & Year"> <span
                                        class="input-group-addon"> <span
                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using angular-loading-bar: this plugin shows a loading animation, blocking every input/action for the user until the loading is complete.

Here is an example:

```
        var promise = BackendService.getData();
        //start the loading animation
        cfpLoadingBar.start();

        promise.then(
            function (data) {
                    //when the server responds, stop the animation
                    cfpLoadingBar.complete();
                }
            },
            function (err) {
                cfpLoadingBar.complete();
                $log.error(err);
            }
        );
    }
```

cfpLoadingBar has to be injected in the controller.
This will block your application until the server response is processed.